# Arrays in raptor

Tags: arrays, vraptor

How can I store an array in my raptor program so I can refer to it for the entire program?

This is what the program's output should look like:

```
Day               Calories Consumed               Calories Burned
Monday               2600                              150
Tuesday              2400                              100
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with three properties

day 
caloriesConsumed 
caloriesBurned

Declare a property in your controller

private Result result;

After serialize a list of objects in your controller.

result.include("listObjects",  List< YourObject >);